# Laravel 5.8 Field 'name doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

Hello im developing a students CRUD in laravel but i have a problem saving the data in my db.

Here is the problem that laravel returns. SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value

My store function.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $alumno = Alumno::create();
        $alumno->fill($request->all());
        $alumno->save();
        return redirect('/alumnos');
    }
```

My model:

```
class Alumno extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','apellido','matricula','correo'];
}
```

My form:

```
<form action="/alumnos" method="post">
    @csrf
    <fieldset class="form-fieldset">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label">Nombre<span class="form-required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label">Apellido<span class="form-required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label">Matricula<span class="form-required">*</span></label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" required name="matricula" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-0">
            <label class="form-label">Correo Electronico<span class="form-required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correo" required />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar" />
</form>
```

What im doing wrong? Please help and thank you!!! :)

Comment: Does the name value shows  in ```$request->all()```

Comment: Can you dump request params? You can do that using dd() . dd($request->all()) and check what request data is passed to controller.

Comment: Try to change form action this way, <form action="{{action('YourController@store')}}" method="post">

Comment: @shihab Hello! This is the return of dd
array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "7RiPoH328tEhME0TKIP3bWJM4q5WvxgQpAvIU6Yb"
  "name" => "Angel"
  "apellido" => "Gomez"
  "matricula" => "131231"
  "correo" => "angel@mail.com"
]

Comment: ```array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "7RiPoH328tEhME0TKIP3bWJM4q5WvxgQpAvIU6Yb"
  "name" => "Angel"
  "apellido" => "Gomez"
  "matricula" => "131231"
  "correo" => "angel@mail.com"
]```

Comment: have you tried with ```$alumno = Alumno::create( $request->all() ); ```. without using fill method

Comment: @shihab Thank you, it works!!! I'll never trust in the documentation anymore x)

Comment: You can set name column to nullable() at migration

Answer (score 0):

You solve this problem in two different ways

1. Your database structure has to be changed like below. Default field must be `Null`. Where description field is your database field.

Like below this

[image]

2. Open your model `database/migrations/your_model` then use like this code

   `Schema::table('your_model', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->string('name')->nullable();
   });`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from the form action URL try to change the action to `{{ action('YourController@store') }}`

Answer (score 0):

You should save data as below:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $alumno = new Alumno();
        $alumno = $alumno->create($request->all());
        return redirect('/alumnos');
    }
```

and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should add line to migration

```
$table->string('name')->nullable();
```

set form as above

```
 <form action="{{action('YourController@store')}}">
```

For insert all request inputs

```
Alumno::create($request->all());
```